# Installation of ZeroMQ does not work on php 5.6 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, zeromq, failed-installation

I have install ZMQ 4.2.2 and additionally installed php5-zmq version 1.1.3

PHP version is  5.6, and OS version is Ubuntu 14.04

Added extension to my

```
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini and /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini extension=zmq.so
```

and when trying to run it, it says

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zmq: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZMQContext' not found in /home/server/vendor/react/zmq/src/React/ZMQ/Context.php on line 15

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. If someone will stuck in the same as i'm do next trick.

```
sudo pecl uninstall zmq-beta
sudo apt-get remove php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev
sudo pecl config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php5.6
```

it will say that

> WARNING: php_bin /usr/bin/php5 appears to have a suffix 5.6, but config variable php_suffix does not match

```
sudo pear config-set php_suffix 5.6
pecl install zmq-beta
```

That will do the rest.